# How can you solve $\lim _{x \to 1}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2x-1}{x}\right)}{\root{3}\of{x}-1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim _{x \to 1}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2x-1}{x}\right)}{\root{3}\of{x}-1}$

I can't use L'Hopital's Rule here. I started by substituting $\root{3}\of{x}-1$ with $t$

$\lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2(t+1)^3-1}{(t+1)^3}\right)}{t} \to \lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(2(t+1)^3-1)-3\cdot\ln{(t+1)}}{t} \to \lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(2(t+1)^3-1)}{t}-3\cdot\frac{\ln{(1+t)}}{t}$

As you can see I formated it so the right part will be $-3$ when I put in $0$. I don't know how to do the left part.

Thanks!

Comment: The left part should come out to be $6\cdot\frac{\ln{(1+t)}}{t}$ but I don't know how to format it.

Comment: Why can't you use L'Hôpital rule? Does the problem ask you?

Comment: In short, no. In long, technically I can use it, but on the test, I won't be able to use it on similar limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(2(t+1)^3-1)}{t}=
\lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(2(t^3+3t^2+3t+1)-1)}{t}
$$
$$
=\lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2t^3+6t^2+6t)}{t}
=\lim _{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2t^3+6t^2+6t)}{2t^3+6t^2+6t}\cdot
\frac{2t^3+6t^2+6t}{t}
$$
$$
=1\cdot \lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{2t^3}{t}+\frac{6t^2}{t}+\frac{6t}{t}\right)
=1\cdot(0+0+6)=6.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(t)=\log (2(t+1)^3-1)$;

$f'(0)=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}=$

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\log (2(t+1)^3-1)-\log 1}{t}$

$=\left (\dfrac{6(t+1)^2}{2(t+1)^3-1}\right )_{t=0}=6.$